# Ruby recursive method with block

Tags: ruby

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```rb
def find_or_wait_for(selector_type, selector, wait = 0)
  sleep(wait) if wait.positive?
  yield if block_given?
  find(selector_type, selector)
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  find_or_wait_for(selector_type, selector, wait + 1) { yield if block_given? } if wait < 5

  raise
end
```

Expected result: same initial block being executed every time the method is called.

Actual result: it executes the block only the first time, it seems like the block is 'lost' inside de rescue.

Comment: If you just want to wait a little longer for the element to appear, you can pass `wait`, e.g. `find(selector_type, selector, wait: 15)`. It waits for up to 15 seconds.

Comment: And regarding your question: instead of calling the method recursively, you could also re-run a failing `begin-rescue-end` block via `retry`. This would also allow to handle the `wait` variable entirely within the method, thus hiding it from the caller.

Answer (score 3):

Capture the block and pass it to the subsequent calls directly.

```rb
def find_or_wait_for(*args, &cb)
  yield if block_given?
  # do something
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  find_or_wait_for(*args, &cb)
  raise
end
```